# Is there a natural Riemannian structure on the total space of a vector bundle?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, vector-bundles

Suppose $B$ is a Riemannian manifold and $\pi: E \to B$ is a smooth vector bundle equipped with a metric.

> Is there a natural Riemannian metric on $E$, i.e. a bundle metric on $TE\to E$?

It seems like there should at least be metrics on $TE$ which restrict to the original Riemannian metric on $TB \subset TE$. I tried to show that the metrics on $E \to B$ and $TB \to B$ give a splitting of the short exact sequence $VE \to TE \to \pi^* TB$ but ended up swimming in symbols.

Comment: Perhaps it's best to think of the simplest case: $E = TB$. Then one can put a Riemannian metric on $TB$ with parallel transport and stuff related to the Levi-Civita connection. I think the answer is probably going to be "You need a connection on $E$" in general; in our case we can pick a special one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As expected in the comment of @MikeMiller, I think the answer is "You need a connection on $E$", although I don't think that it has to be a linear connetion. As you pointed out in the question, for each point $u\in E$, there is an exact sequence $0\to V_uE\to T_uE\to T_{\pi(u)}B\to 0$. Since $E$ is a vector bundle $V_uE$ is canonically isomorphic to $E_u$, the fiber of $E$ over $u$. So the Riemannian metric on $B$ and the bundle metric on $E$ give you inner products on $T_{\pi(u)}B$ and $V_uE$, respectively.

Now an inner product on $T_uE$ which "fits into the sequence" is equivalent to specifying a subspace $H_uE$ in $T_uE$, which is complementary to $V_u$. (Given the inner product, take $H_uE$ to be $(V_uE)^\perp$, given the space $H_uE$, identify it with $T_{\pi(u)}B$ via the bundle projection, pull back the inner product and declare the sum to be orthogonal.) But a choice of complementary subspace is just a connection on the fiber bundle $\pi:E\to B$ (it is not neccesarily a linear connection on the vector bundle $E$).

In special situations, there may be a way to choose a specific connection by requiring some additional properties, but in general I don't see a way how to make a canonical choice.

Comment: Thanks.  I gathered something similar from Mike's comment, so it's helpful to see that it all lines up.  The question occurred to me in the context of almost-Kähler manifolds, so there might be enough structure to single out some natural connections.